# Get a string between two words

Tags: regex

This `\[(.*?)\]` gets string between `[` and `]`. Now I want to get string between one word and another one. I've tried `\wword1(.*?)\wword2`, no success. Help me, what am I doing wrong?

String example:

> The engine word1 has successfully word2 matched the word is in our
>   string, skipping the two earlier occurrences of the characters i and
>   s. If we had used the regular expression is, it would have matched the
>   is in This.

Output example: `has succesfully`

Comment: Remove the `\w` and you are good to go.

Comment: P.S. I don't want word1 and word2 included in the new string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=word1)(stringbetween)(?=word2)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22282897)

Comment: @lelloman I don't see the problem. I think this answers the question.

Comment: This answer had been flagged as low quality and my comment was a template spawned by the review. I still think it could be improved with an explanation though, _"try this"_ yes, but why is this the solution to the problem?

Comment: @lelloman I agree with you that some explanations would make this answer better. This is a solution since OP wrote *"I don't want word1 and word2 included in the new string"* and lookarounds like `(?<=)` and `(?=)` make sure that things are there without including them into the match.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way-

```
word1 ([a-zA-Z\s]+) word2
```

**OR**

Your way after removing unnecessary `\w` before and after

```
word1 (.*?) word2
```

**REGEX:** https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/20

Answer (score 0):

When you add `\w` to the pattern, it will match a word character and it is expected.

What you might do is remove that and match 1+ times a whitespace character after the first word and before the second word.

Then your match in the first capturing group:

```
\bword1\s+(.*?)\s+word2\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/seCxo6/1)

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `word1` Match literaly
- `\s+` Match 1+ times a whitespace char
- `(.*?)` Capture in a group any char 0+ times non greedy
- `\s+` Match 1+ times a whitespace char
- `word2` Match literally
- `\b` Word boundary

Answer (score 0):

> this `[(.?)]` gets string between `[` and `]`.

No it doesn't, it should be `\[[^\]]*\]` to get any string between [ and ]

The solution is:

```
\bword1(.*?)\bword2
```

`\w` is a word character `[A-Za-z)-9]` and some more. `\b` is a word boundary, what you are looking for. It might even be

```
\bword1\b(.*?)\bword2\b
```

Comment: Thanks Lonely Neuron